# Does always gradients in mini-batch SGD have to be unbiased in order to prove convergence?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent

I am currently reading this paper [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.11028) and [[2]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9439935).

The authors state that:

> Our analytical results include almost all of the unbiased compression
> techniques.

And also:

> (i) gradient compression must be unbiased to ensure convergence of the
> learning, which is the same condition that we have for SGD to be an
> unbiased estimation of Full-batch Gradient Descent (FGD).

I am wondering does always gradients in mini-batch SGD have to be unbiased in order to prove convergence?

Comment: Yes, this is necessary -- the intuition is that, if you're taking noisy gradient steps, you should at least be "going in the right direction" on average. The proof is here, and relies on the mini-batch gradient (called a noisy subgradient) being unbiased. http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/stoch_subgrad_slides.pdf